# Wordpress and MySQL, putting a column of results into an array

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a column in MySQL in the following format after I run a certain `$sql`:

```
colname
12
15
10
23
12
2
```

What I want is to transfer this into

```
    $colname = array(12,15,10,23,12,2)
```

I came up with:

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
$colname=array();
foreach($results as $result){
$colname[] = $result;}
```

Is this the most efficient way? **The order is also very important**

Comment: This looks reasonably good. (With few exceptions) databases are designed to access *tables*, composed of *rows*, composed of *fields*... There isn't normally any way to retrieve a *column* as understood by a spreadsheet.

Comment: just use the `$result` var. It is already the array you need. See it using `var_dump($result);`

Comment: Rows in an RDBMS have no order, so the premise of the question is flawed.

Comment: @Strawberry but if I order by lets say DESC id, they should still be in that order

Comment: We can only comment on the question asked. There is no id here.

Comment: @JorgeCampos I tried it, but no array was given, I got a string instead.

Comment: The `$result` itself is an array. The `var_dump` command is just to show its content.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use something like:

```
$sql = 
    "SELECT " .
    "    group_concat(colname ORDER BY order_by SEPARATOR ',') AS txt_result " .
    "FROM " .
    "    t ; " ;  

$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
$colname = split(',', $results[0]['txt_result'])
```

Note that you need a certain `ORDER BY` expression. By default, SQL does *not* provide any determined order. `$colname` will be an array of *textual representations* of your numbers. You should convert them to *numbers* if need to.

See the result of the SQL query at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=318091f09900b422636407965d1eee99)*

---

Reference:

- [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php)

Comment: I see no advantage in this method

Comment: @Strawberry: There isn't much. The amount of data moved will be slightly less. It's just a way to show how to convert from columns to rows; and how to make the database work more, and your PHP code work less.